# SFTP: IOException while reading a file with java

Tags: java, apache-poi, sftp, jsch

I am using com.jcraft.jsch library to read .xls files from an SFTP server. Following is the code to connect to server.

```
    session = jsch.getSession(username, host);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.connect();
    sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    sftpChannel.connect();
```

I am using `sftpChannel.get(file)` to retrieve inputStream to the file. This inputstream is then used to instantiate `XSSFWorkbook` as shown below:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
```

*Problem 1*:

When I run the app, it seems to get stuck on the above line for some time (say 5 minutes) and then it throws `java.io.IOException: Pipe closed` error.
The xls file I am trying to read is 800kb and it works fine when run from local machine.

*Problem 2*:

The app is designed to process files sequentially. So, if first file fails with IOE, rest of the files also fail as the connection is timed out. To prevent this, I put the below code to check and re-connect:

```
if(null == session || !session.isConnected()){
        log.debug("Session is not connected/timed out. Creating a new session");
        openSftpSession();
        log.debug("New session is created");
    }
//openSftpSession() is the code to create a new session as explained in the beginning of the question.
```

When this code gets executed, following exception gets thrown:

```
java.io.IOException: error: 4: RequestQueue: unknown request id 1028332337
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2.read(ChannelSftp.java:1407)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
//More lines
```

***edit*** : code to retrieve input stream

```
public InputStream getInputStream(String folder, String file) throws Exception{
    sftpChannel.cd(root + folder);
    log.debug("current directory:" + sftpChannel.pwd());
    log.debug("File :" + folder + " " + file);
    return sftpChannel.get(file);
}
```

Can anyone please help me get over this? I believe an alternate approach to prevent timeout is to download the file in some temp directory and process. However, I don't really want to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code that is calling `sftpChannel.get()` and the code which is triggering the exception? Is `new XSSFWorkbook()` actually getting any data from the remote server, or does it just block on the first read until the timeout? How much data does it actually read from the remote server before the connection times out?

Comment: I have added the code to get the Input stream. I am getting the input stream, when I print in.available(), it prints 0. Also, I believe in.read() hangs. I have tried the solution suggested by Brendan but now it hangs on  `IOUtils.toByteArray` method.

Comment: I have set the keep alive time to 1 minute, so connection doesn't get timed out now. However, it hangs on read() forever.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see whether the approach you describe (download into temp file) works? Just to verify that your inputstream is ok.. How long does it take to download into a local file over that connection?

If you don't want to manage a temp file you could always pull it into a byte[] in memory, so long as you don't have to scale to much more than 800kbs.. Use *Apache Commons* as such:

```
InputStream in = sftpChannel.get(file);
byte[] inBytes = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(in)
ByteArrayInputStream inByteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inBytes)
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inByteStream);
```

As for the Request Id, it looks like the old session/channel is still trying to do a read but is no longer able to. Maybe you aren't closing out that session/channel properly. From the openSftpSession() code it looks like you would only be overwriting the references without properly shutting them down.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Brendan, I have just set the aliveInterval of connection to 60000 (i.e. 1 set alive ping every minute). Now, it doesn't get timed out now but it seems to be taking forever! It has been more than 35 minutes and the XSSFWorkbook hasn't been created yet! I can sort that request id out by single-threading it. And yes, let me try the approach of storing the data into byte array. Hope it doesn't create memory issues ;)

Comment: As long as you have enough virtual memory, you can get away with storing the file content in a byte array.